# Wind effect on a drone: formulation

Tags: quadcopter, drone

When the drone flies in the open space the wind acting on it creates aerodynamic drag force and the aerodynamic torque. So when I want to simulate the drone flight using the state space equation do we need to consider drag force when computing drone linear acceleration only or the wind effect also changes the torque so it affects the pitch, roll and yaw?

So far my state is described as :
\begin{equation}
\dot{z}_{q} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{x} \\
\dot{y} \\
\dot{z} \\
\dot{q_0}\\
\dot{q_1}\\
\dot{q_2}\\
\dot{q_3}\\
\ddot{x} \\
\ddot{y} \\
\ddot{z} \\
\ddot{\phi}\\
\ddot{\theta}\\
\ddot{\psi}\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{x} \\
\dot{y} \\
\dot{z} \\
-0.5\dot{\phi} q_1 - 0.5\dot{\theta} q_2 - 0.5q_3 \dot{\psi} \\
0.5\dot{\phi} q_0 - 0.5\dot{\theta} q_3 + 0.5q_2 \dot{\psi} \\
0.5\dot{\phi} q_3 + 0.5\dot{\theta} q_0 - 0.5q_1 \dot{\psi} \\
-0.5\dot{\phi} q_2 + 0.5\dot{\theta} q_1 + 0.5q_0 \dot{\psi} \\
\begin{aligned}
&D_x- 2(q_0 q_2 + q_1 q_3)(U_1 + U_2 + U_3 + U_4)
\end{aligned} \\
\begin{aligned}
D_y-2(q_0 q_1 - q_2 q_3)(U_1 + U_2 + U_3 + U_4)
\end{aligned} \\
\begin{aligned}
D_z-(q_0^2 - q_1^2 - q_2^2 + q_3^2)(U_1 + U_2 + U_3 + U_4) + m_bg
\end{aligned} \\
\begin{aligned}
&(I_{Byy} - I_{Bzz}) \dot{\phi} \dot{\psi} - I_{Rzz}(w_{M1} - w_{M2} + w_{M3} - w_{M4}) \dot{\phi}+(U_1 - U_2 - U + U_4) l_x
\end{aligned} \\
\begin{aligned}
(I_{Bzz} - I_{Bxx})\dot{\theta} \dot{\psi} + I_{Rzz}(w_{M1} - w_{M2} + w_{M3} - w_{M4})\dot{\theta}+(U_1 + U_2 - U_3 - U_4) l_y
\end{aligned} \\
(I_{Bxx} - I_{Byy})\dot{\theta}\dot{\phi} -( T_1 - T_2 + T_3 - T_4)
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
where $l_x, l_y$ is the length of the arms of the quadrotor in x, y directions from the center of its mass to the center of the motors, $l_z$ height of the motor.
\begin{equation}
D_x = -\frac{1}{2} \rho  C_{dx} A_x w_x^2 (w_x-\dot{x}) \\
D_y =- \frac{1}{2} \rho  C_{dy} A_y w_y^2 (w_y-\dot{y})\\
D_z = -\frac{1}{2} \rho  C_{dz} A_z w_z^2 (w_z-\dot{z})
\end{equation}
Where
\begin{equation}
U_i=k_{tr}\omega_i^2
\end{equation}
where $U_i$ is the thrust of the $i^{th}$motor, $k_{tr}$ is a thrust coefficient and $\omega_i$ is a the motor's angular velocity. Torque is computed in the similar manner as:

\begin{equation}
T_i=k_{tor}\omega_i^2
\end{equation}
where $T_i$ is the torque of the $i^{th}$motor, $k_{tor}$ is a torque coefficient.

So in that formulation wind effects only accounted in the acceleration but not anywhere else, does it seem correct? Or do I need to also include it in my $[\ddot{\phi} \ \ddot{\theta} \ \ddot{\psi} ]^T$ computation?